# Java writing simple program

Tags: java

I am writing a simple program that the user has to input the name of the employee, wage per hour and how many hours he will work and it will give out the name of the employee as well as how much he earned gross pay and net pay this week but I can't find a way to input the name as a text not a number.

```
class payroll
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double count, hours, wage, grosspay, netpay;
    int employee;
    for (;;)
    {
    System.out.print(" Please input the name of the employee followed by the hourly wage followed by the hours worked ");
    employee=input.nextDouble();
    hours = input.nextDouble();
    wage= input.nextDouble();
    grosspay= hours*wage;
    netpay= hours*wage*0.7;
    System.out.print( employee + " gross pay will be " + grosspay + " pounds." + employee + " net pay will be " + netpay + " pounds " + "Please insert name, hours and wage of the next worker." );
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method to read a `String`:

```
employee = input.next();
```

Comment: I changed it like you said and it still doesnt work. It gives error when trying to javac. "Requierd int Found: String"

Comment: You also need to change the type of `employee` from `int` to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

this is what is needed(mentioned by Arrem as an answer before)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String abc = in.nextLine(); 
System.out.println("You entered string "+ abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nextLine()` to do it and you should be ok.